# Как открыть pop-up окно с другой страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть 2 страницы, допустим, главная и админка. Как при клике на кнопку или на ссылку на странице админка, сделать так, чтобы на главной странице всплывало pop-up окно, для всех кто в данный момент смотрит главную страницу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пошлите им сообщение по websocket.

Answer (score 1):

для этого идеально подойдет протокол связи WebSocket, для общения клиента и сервера. Вам нужно оповестить всех клиентов по WebSocket протоколу, что нужно показать модальное окно.